# How to override create method in polymorphic relations in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, polymorphic-associations

I have two models `UserReport` and `Person`. They are related polymorphically by the following relations:

```
// models/Person.php
public function reports()
{
    return $this->morphMany('UserReport', 'reportable');
}

// models/UserReport.php
public function reportable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Following is the code that I use to create a new report for the person based on the input provided by the user.

```
$input = Input::all();
$person = Person::find($input['id']);
$person->reports()->create($input);
```

I want to override the above mentioned `create` method so that I can perform some validation and some other operations on the data everytime the `create` method is called.

In the model `UserReport`, I created a `create` method to override it, but it is called only when `UserReport::create` is done.

```
// models/UserReport.php
public static function create(array $input)
{
    // some operations here
    return parent::create($attributes);
}
```

So the question is how do I override the `create` method in `$person->reports()->create($input)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you may use an event like this (Put this inside your `UserReport` model):

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::saving(function($userReport){
        if(!static::validates($userReport)) return false;
        return true;
    });
}

// Declare some rules, i.e.
protected static $rules = array(
    'name' => 'required|alpha',
    'description' => 'required'
);

// validate function
protected static function validates($UserReport)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($UserReport->getAttributes(), static::$rules);
    if($validator->fails()) return false;
    return true;
}
```

This is a basic idea and you may make it better by using an abstract (base) class for `validates` function and use this abstract class to create all other models so all models share the same `validates` method and make your base class extend the `Eloquent`. Also add some logic to get errors if validation fails. You may check this [nice article](http://driesvints.com/blog/using-laravel-4-model-events).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had totally forgot about model events.